# IronPython and Javascript execution via C# isn't consistent?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net-4.0, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is JavaScript’s Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I wrote some simple C# code that runs Python code dynamically (already implemented):

```
string code = @"100 * 2 + 4 / 3";
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Expression);
int res = source.Execute<int>();
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

And then I thought about Javascript, and that there are core differences between C# and JS. For example:

In JS:

```
var t=1.02+1.01 = 2.0300000000000002;
```

And then I tried this via [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/):

```
var script = @"
  function add( ) {
    return 1.02 + 1.01;
  };
  return add();";
  var result = new JintEngine().Run(script);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The result was:

[image]

Maybe I don't see the whole picture, but if a programmer on the other side of the world sends me his script file, I (and him) expect the result to be consistent! (Let's **ignore** the problematic base 2 representation for now, I'm talking about consistency).

If I was mistaken, in what scenario would I use running other code on .Net? (I will have to be very very suspicious for *every line* of code...)

Am I right ?

## another Example :

```
   var script = @"
                               function show( )
                               {
                                      return  parseInt('123asd'); //in js it's 123
                               };
                               return show();";

                var result = new JintEngine().Run(script);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
```

result :

[image]

How can I trust a script to yield the same expected result ? ( or am I getting this whole situation wrong...?)

Comment: just to make clear you saying that you see the problem in js with extra decimal points 2.0300000000000002;

Comment: @COLDTOLD this is one example. I can fill this whole page with inconstant result of execution....( and that's what i'm afraid from)

Comment: I think if the result is of just by decimal poitns 2.0300 and the other one is 2.03 it theoretically the same and both parties have to agree on decimal point  but if the actulal number is off like 3.0300 and the number is  2.0300  than it a problem it might also be that the  I ronPython implementation might be rounding number while js just gives you a huge decimal point result

Comment: @paulsm4 my question  talks about the same code  , different environment inconsistency. I don't understand why you suggest the question to be closed.

Comment: @paulsm4 see my edit. is this also releated to broken math in JS ?

Comment: "Javascript math" is *NOT* broken.  The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken) explains why.  It also, I believes, answers your question.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I know it is not broken. see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any "inconsistency".  That's just how floating point numbers work!

1) The value - by definition - is seldom "exact"

2) The representation (e.g. from Printing out to a string) can be totally misleading if you try to print out more digits than your value has precision :)

Sample C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int 
main ()
{
  double d = 1.02 + 1.01;
  float f = 1.02 + 1.01;
  printf ("d=%lf, f=%f\n", d, f);
  printf ("d=%25.20lf, f=%25.20f\n", d, f);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
d=2.030000, f=2.030000
d=   2.03000000000000020000, f=   2.02999997138977050000
```

Excellent article:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Finally, please read this discussion:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

The problem is NOT Python, it's NOT C#, it's NOT Javascript.

I assure you :)

Comment: if js shows A and c# shows B  , for me thats incosistancy. This can crash the whole Program. :)

Comment: p.s. I already read this article several times. I know exactly how it works. :-)

Comment: do you realize that this kind of inconsistency can crash your program....do you ? ( **that's what my whole question is about**)

Answer (score 2):

This is no error, what you are witnessing is how computers store decimal numbers.
This subject is rather complicated... Computers cannot store the exact numeral for a decimal number, when you added together 1.01 and 1.02, you got exactly what the computer thought the result was.

It is not unusual for you to get this. What i suggest you do in this situation is round the number to the decimal placement you want (e.g. the hundredths placement, for you). But this will only work when dealing with larger numbers. When you want to deal with smaller, more precise decimals, you are going to have to either deal with it, or get a super computer.

Comment: Didn't I already write that ? ( the base 2 representation). I can provide more example of incosistency. if I have another code , I dont want start dealing with corrections. otherwise , let me build it myself.

Comment: Computers can store decimal numbers exactly, but they can't use a `double` for it. For example .net has the `System.Decimal` type which you can use if you need exact representation of decimal numbers.

Comment: @Royi Namir - you're simply mistaken in your understanding of how things "should" work.  Nikku Aisuru is absolutely correct.  All *you* have to do to insure "consistent" results is limit the #/decimal places you're printing out in your string!

Comment: @paulsm4 did you see my second sample  ( the edit) ?